# Maximum update depth exceeded- React component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement lazy loading in my react component. But whenever I update my state in reducer after calling the (loadMore) function it gives me this error.

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Here is my article rendering file where i am implementing lazy loading. I am not setState anywhere in the render. I am not able to understand where the error is.
This component is called in article container.
Below is the table.js component code-

---

```
class Table extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
}

loadMore = () => {
    if (this.props.articleReducer.article_data.length > 0) {
        this.props.dispatch(loadArticleDataApi(2, 'lazyLoad'));
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <InfiniteScroll pageStart={1} loadMore={this.loadMore} initialLoad={true}
                hasMore={true} loader={< div className = "loader" key = {0}> Loading ...</div>}>
                <div className="table">
                    <div className="container ">
                        <div className="show-grid row">
                            <div className="col-xs-4 head1">Title</div>
                            <div className="col-xs-2 head2">Pub All</div>
                            <div className="col-xs-2 head3">Publisher</div>
                            <div className="col-xs-2 head4">Rss</div>
                            <div className="col-xs-1 head5">AMP</div>
                            <div className="col-xs-1 head7">Publish</div>
                        </div>
                        {this.props.articleReducer.article_data.map((ele, index) => {
                                let hreff = `https://so.city/amp/delhi/${ele._id}.html`;
                                return (

                                    <div className="show-grid row rowData" key={index}>
                                        <div className="col-xs-4">{ele.title}</div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-2">
                                            <SwitchButtonPubAll checkedProp={ele.allFeedPublished}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-2 publisher">{ele.createdBy}</div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-2">
                                            <SwitchButton checkedProp={ele.rssCreated}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-1 amp">
                                            <i className="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            &nbsp;
                                            <a href={hreff}>
                                                <i className="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-xs-1">
                                            <i
                                                className={ele.published === 1
                                                ? "fa fa-eye eyee"
                                                : "fa fa-eye-slash"}
                                                aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    )
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {dispatch};
}
export default connect(state => state, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you using [React Infinite Scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using [React Infinite Scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller) and this answer is based on that.

The problem is that you are setting `hasMore={true}`. When you scroll to the end of page and `hasMore` is `true`, the component request more data by call `loadMore`, the new data is the same as the previous one (so the page is not scrolled up) but `hasMore` is still `true` (it must be `false` to tells the component that there is no new data) so it calls `loadMore` again, and again,... and crash.

**Solution:** Provide a mechanic to check if there is new data available and pass it to `hasMore`